# Error compiling Grok

Tags: grok

I tried to compile the grok based on the this link http://linuxdrops.com/log-management-using-logstash-and-kibana-on-centos-rhel-fedora/ but encounter below problem. Hope someone can help me to solve the problem that I encounter.

```
[root@eul2400508 grok]# make 
cc -c -pipe -fPIC -I. -O2 -I/usr/local/include -DPLATFORM_GNULinux  grok.c -o grok.o
In file included from grok.c:1:
grok.h:8:20: error: tcutil.h: No such file or directory
In file included from grok.c:1:
grok.h:39: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘TCTREE’
In file included from grok.h:132,
                 from grok.c:1:
grok_pattern.h:7: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
In file included from grok.h:140,
                 from grok.c:1:
grok_discover.h:9: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘TCTREE’
grok.c: In function ‘grok_init’:
grok.c:27: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘re’
grok.c:30: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘pcre_capture_vector’
grok.c:31: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘pcre_num_captures’
grok.c:32: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘max_capture_num’
grok.c:33: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘pcre_errptr’
grok.c:34: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘pcre_erroffset’
grok.c:35: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘logmask’
grok.c:36: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘logdepth’
grok.c:39: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘patterns’
grok.c:43: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘captures_by_id’
grok.c:44: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘captures_by_name'
grok.c:45: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘captures_by_subname’
grok.c:46: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘captures_by_capture_number’
grok.c:56: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘pcre_errptr’
grok.c:57: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘pcre_erroffset’
[root@eul2400508 grok]# make 
cc -c -pipe -fPIC -I. -O2 -I/usr/local/include -DPLATFORM_GNULinux  grok.c -o grok.o
In file included from grok.c:1:
grok.h:8:20: error: tcutil.h: No such file or directory
In file included from grok.c:1:
grok.h:39: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘TCTREE’
In file included from grok.h:132,
                 from grok.c:1:
grok_pattern.h:7: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
In file included from grok.h:140,
                 from grok.c:1:
grok_discover.h:9: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘TCTREE’
grok.c: In function ‘grok_init’:
grok.c:27: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘re’
grok.c:30: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘pcre_capture_vector’
grok.c:31: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘pcre_num_captures’
grok.c:32: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘max_capture_num’
grok.c:33: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘pcre_errptr’
grok.c:34: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘pcre_erroffset’
grok.c:35: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘logmask’
grok.c:36: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘logdepth’
grok.c:39: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘patterns’
grok.c:43: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘captures_by_id’
grok.c:44: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘captures_by_name'
grok.c:45: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘captures_by_subname’
grok.c:46: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘captures_by_capture_number’
grok.c:56: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘pcre_errptr’
grok.c:57: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘pcre_erroffset’
grok.c:60: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘pcre_errptr’
grok.c:62: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘pcre_erroffset’
grok.c: In function ‘grok_clone’:
grok.c:78: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘patterns’
grok.c:78: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘patterns’
grok.c:79: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘logmask’
grok.c:79: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘logmask’
grok.c:80: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘logdepth’
grok.c:80: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘logdepth’
grok.c: In function ‘grok_pcre_callout’:
grok.c:114: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘logmask’
grok.c:114: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘logdepth’
grok.c:119: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘logmask’
grok.c:119: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘logdepth’
grok.c:124: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘logmask’
grok.c:124: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘logdepth’
make: *** [grok.o] Error 1
grok.c:60: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘pcre_errptr’
grok.c:62: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘pcre_erroffset’
grok.c: In function ‘grok_clone’:
grok.c:78: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘patterns’
grok.c:78: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘patterns’
grok.c:79: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘logmask’
grok.c:79: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘logmask’
grok.c:80: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘logdepth’
grok.c:80: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘logdepth’
grok.c: In function ‘grok_pcre_callout’:
grok.c:114: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘logmask’
grok.c:114: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘logdepth’
grok.c:119: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘logmask’
grok.c:119: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘logdepth’
grok.c:124: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘logmask’
grok.c:124: error: ‘grok_t’ has no member named ‘logdepth’
make: *** [grok.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue but on debian and was able to resolve by:

1. Making sure I had all dependencies:  found in the Makefile - line 269

   - bison
   - ctags
   - flex
   - gperf
   - libevent-dev
   - libpcre3-dev
   - libtokyocabinet-dev
2. I also followed the instructions I [found here](https://code.google.com/p/semicomplete/wiki/Grok) in the comment by "wheel...@gmail.com" but am not sure if this was necessary.

> The Makefile can be fixed by changing the two gcc lines which look like this:
>
> > `gcc $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@`
> >
> > To this:
> >
> > `gcc $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@`
> >
> > And of course update the CFLAGS and LDFLAGS to point to correct directories.

Answer (score 0):

To `make grok` on Ubuntu 12.04 I needed to update the two gcc lines as mentioned above (by moving $(LDFLAGS) after the $^) but it seems I didn't need to do whatever this means:

> "update the CFLAGS and LDFLAGS to point to correct directories."

Answer (score 0):

On Centos you'll need to have the same packages mentioned about, though they are named differently (just the last three):

```
bison
ctags
flex
gperf
libevent-devel
libprcre3-devel
tokyocabinet-dev
```